# Required attribtue not working when using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

Ive found similar questions but none that seem to answer my question.  I have a form, with some details that I want to be required.  Some that I dont.  I have a required tag in the ones I do.  The submit button is outside the form, but linked to it using the form attribute.  When the submit button is pressed, I want it to update a array, with a new object.  But it updates even if the required fields (first name and surname) are empty.  How do I make sure that the form only updates the array if there are values in the first name and surname input fields?

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-overlay" id="newPersonFormCtr">
<div class="form-content">
    <div class="mainbox-title">Personal details</div>
    <form name="newPersonForm" method="post" action=""> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstname" class="form-control" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Surname</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="form-control" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Favorite food</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fav-food" name="fav-food" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<button class="addBtn" form="newPersonForm" id="addPersonBtn" type="submit" onclick="addPerson()">Add Person</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
let people = [
        {
            firstName : 'John',
            surname : 'Adams',
        }]  
function addPerson(){
    var newPerson = 
        {  
        'firstName' : document.newPersonForm.firstname.value, 
        'surname' : document.newPersonForm.surname.value 
        }
    people.push(newPerson);
    console.log(people);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required attribute works different ways in different browsers. You should use JavaScript validation instead of HTML. Check the value and make sure they are not empty before pushing to the array. Hopefully, this would be help.

```
let people = [
        {
            firstName : 'John',
            surname : 'Adams',
        }]  
function addPerson(){

    let firstName = document.newPersonForm.firstname.value,
    surename = document.newPersonForm.surname.value;

    if(firstName === '' || surename === '') return false;
    // more validation here
    
    var newPerson = 
        {  
        'firstName' : firstName, 
        'surname' : surename 
        }
    people.push(newPerson);
    console.log(people);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the javascript file I suppose...

```
const firstName = document.getElementById('first-name')
const surname = document.getElementById('surname')

let people = [
        {
            firstName : 'John',
            surname : 'Adams',
        }]  
function addPerson(){
  if(firstName.value !== "" && surname.value !== "") {
      var newPerson = 
          {  
          'firstName' : document.newPersonForm.firstname.value, 
          'surname' : document.newPersonForm.surname.value 
          }
      people.push(newPerson);
      console.log(people);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length || str.trim().length === 0);
}

function addPerson(){
    if(!isEmpty(document.newPersonForm.firstname.value) && 
    !isEmpty(document.newPersonForm.surname.value)){
    var newPerson = 
        {  
        'firstName' : document.newPersonForm.firstname.value, 
        'surname' : document.newPersonForm.surname.value 
        }
    people.push(newPerson);
    console.log(people);
    }
    else alert("Inputs are required");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use onsubmit event listener instead of onclick event

Like this:

```
<button class="addBtn" form="newPersonForm" id="addPersonBtn" type="submit" onsubmit="addPerson()">Add Person</button>
```

But not this:

```
<button class="addBtn" form="newPersonForm" id="addPersonBtn" type="submit" onclick="addPerson()">Add Person</button>
```

then add id attribute to form element like this

```
<form id="newPersonForm" name="newPersonForm" method="post" action="">
// code here ....
<form/>
```